# flutter How to add loop in final list Widget according to the data from database?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview, flutter-image

I want to show images in loop which are store in List widget but this are static data.
like this:-
final List imgs = [
"assets/images/people.png",
"assets/images/people.png",
"assets/images/people.png",
"assets/images/people.png",
"assets/images/people.png",
];

now I want to show this list with dynamic data and that's why I have an API that returns the images from the database. now I want to show that images in `final List<String> imgs = []` widget. so how do I add the loop in this widget? please help me.
In images, I store the image URL which comes from a database.
I want to show the images in the `List widget`

here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:mindmatch/utils/Auth.dart';
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

class ProfileImages extends StatefulWidget {

ProfileImages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_ProfileImages createState() => _ProfileImages();
}

class _ProfileImages extends State<ProfileImages>{

 var UsrID = Auth.prefs?.getString('usrid');
 var Imagedata;
 var Images = "";

 @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();

  getImageData();

 }

 getImageData() async{
 var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', '/mm_api/index.php',{'act':'usrPhotos','UsrID': '${UsriD}'}));
 var jsonData = json.decode(res.body);
 var images = jsonData.map<String>((json) => json['image']).toList();
//print(images);

 setState(() {
  for(var img in images){
    imgs.add(img);
  }
 });
 }

 final List<String> imgs = [];




@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


return
  Imagedata != null?GFItemsCarousel(
  rowCount: 3,
  //itemHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
  children: imgs.map(
        (url) {
      return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: imgs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            //check the image if it is asset or network
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                      child:
                      Image.network(imgs[index]),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 9,
                      right: 9,
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        width: 30,
                        'assets/images/close.svg',
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],

                ),
              );

          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ).toList(),
): const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
);
}
}
```

at the Images variable, I store the full image URL from the database but how do I show this in `List widget` please help me with how I show these images in the loop.

here is my JSON data:-

```
[{"id":"8","image":"5e11b3c030f07b70ee982158bccff41f.jpeg"},{"id":"9","image":"158ad385dff9ec07a40d4401351de434.jpeg"},{"id":"10","image":"af8079a1832c0458b80ac17c865a840b.jpeg"}]
```

here is a new error please anyone helps me.[image: it shows me invalid argument error]

Please help with how I show these images.

Comment: Use ListView.builder() and assign the image source like> Imagedata[index].image  [more](https://www.fluttertpoint.com/listview-in-flutter-example). Don't use the model class, you can set the images directly without the Model class.

Answer (score 0):

Extract images from response and added it to the `imgs` list .

````
  var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', '/mm_api/index.php',{'act':'usrPhotos','UsrID': '${UsrID}'}));
  Imagedata = jsonDecode(res.body);

  
  imgs.clear();
  ImagesData.forEach((e){
imgs.add(e.image);

})

 }```

Then after 

ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
              child:

//append with baseURL
              Image.network(
             "https://www.*******.net/files/profile/" +   url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
````

Comment: which type of variable added for `imgs`?

Comment: You have already specified string so added in it List<String> imgs

Comment: but in that `imgs` I added static data. how can i replace with dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

use `ListView.builder` like this:

for asset images

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: img.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return new Image.asset(img[index], fit: BoxFit.cover);
 },
);
```

for images from network

```
 ListView.builder(
      itemCount: urls.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Image.network(urls[index]);
      },
    );
  }
```

you can use `cached_network_image` to get an image from the network only once and then get it from the local cache

for your example after getting an images successfully from database merge them with `imgs` list

change  `getImageData` to

```
 getImageData() async{
  var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', '/mm_api/index.php',{'act':'usrPhotos','UsrID': '${UsrID}'}));
  var jsonData = json.decode(res.body);
  var images = jsonData.map<String>((json) => json['image']).toList();
  
  setState(() {
     for(var img in images){
       imgs.add(img);
   }  
  });
 }
```

change `build` to

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Profile Images"),
    ),
    body: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: imgs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          //check the image if it is asset or network 
          if(imgs[index].contains("assets")){
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Image.asset(imgs[index]),
            );
          }else{
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Image.network(imgs[index]),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: it shows me the `Undefined name 'urls'.`

Comment: `urls` should be the list of images
`List<String> urls=["https://picsum.photos/200", "https://picsum.photos/100", "https://picsum.photos/300"]`

Comment: but these urls are static right? I want to show dynamic data. I changed some code in my question

Comment: so you want to show static images than after the data is loaded from the database you want to replace that static images with network images?

Comment: no i just want to show dynamic images not static after load and before load

Comment: if i add Listbuilder it shows me error on line `urls = "https://www.*******.net/files/profile/${Imagedata['image']}";` that `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index',`

Comment: I have edited to answer

Comment: I edit my question please see this error

Comment: it does not show any image shows `Exception: Invalid Image data`